# ajax call in window.unload event of IE issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, browser

when a user closes their browser or refresh the browser(onbeforeunload event does NOT fit for my scenario, seems user may cancle to leave), I want to send a log to server, so I have the following code, it works **fine** in chrome and FireFox, but **NOT** work in IE8+:

```
 window.onunload = function(){
                   $.ajax({url:"http://localhost:8888/log",async:false})
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **onbeforeunload** event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: the problem is onbeforeunload will pop a window, if user click "cancel to leave", I want NOT to log to server